# For loop iteration seemingly skips two numbers in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running the code below, I can't understand why it doesn't remove all 1's? It keeps two of them and with my two print statements added before the if statement, it shows the program seemingly skipping over the last 2 of the 4 1's. I know of an easier way to do this, I'm just trying to understand the logic of why this isn't working.

```
numbers3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9]
print(numbers3.count(1))

for number in numbers3:
    print(numbers3.count(number))
    print(number)
    if numbers3.count(number) > 1:
        numbers3.remove(number)
print(numbers3)
```

I expect the out put to be [1, 4, 5, 7, 9]
But instead I get [1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The problem is that you are modifying the list you are iterating over, which is rarely a recipe for a happy result in Python (or most other languages).

It's fairly common to see questions from beginners that usefully tell us what the expected output is, but not why. Reading your code, I deduce (or rather guess) that you would like a list containing a single copy of each unique number.

One way to achieve your end is to build a separate list of the numbers you want. So this (untested) should work:

```
result = []
for number in numbers3:
    if number not in result:
        result.append(number)
```

A simpler way, which since Python 3.6 should retain ordering, would be

```
result = list(set(numbers3))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the result I was after and the code you have is correct (its the answer in the exercise I was working on.

So in the future it's generally a good idea to avoid modifying the same list that is being iterated over? Instead, it would be a better idea to create a new list based upon logic applied to the original list.

Thanks again.

Comment: That's correct. Generally speaking in Python we tend to create new objects by iterating over existing ones. If the input is no longer required we often use the same name for the result, but I felt that might be a little too confusing. Re-using the name means the storage occupied by the input can be freed immediately, but this is usually a minor consideration.

Comment: And, I forgot to say, unless you specifically need a list, since Python 3.6 (?) if you just want to iterate over the set, `set(numbers3)` wins hands-down!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because youre removing from the list meanwhile iterating over it. you remove [1,1] and then the 4 becomes the 2th index and it skips the other [1,1].